# When ever I run roscore, this error prompts. How can I fix this issue ? Please provide a solution

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore", line 36, in <module>
        from rosmaster.master_api import NUM_WORKERS
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
        from .main import rosmaster_main
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/main.py", line 43, in <module>
        import rosmaster.master
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/master.py", line 47, in <module>
        import rosmaster.master_api
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 72, in <module>
        from rosmaster.util import xmlrpcapi
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/util.py", line 48, in <module>
        from defusedxml.xmlrpc import monkey_patch
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'defusedxml'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. and tried installing defusedxml. but no use

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372612/when-ever-i-run-roscore,-this-error-prompts.-how-can-i-fix-this-issue-?-please-provide-a-solution./) by [Sreevalsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/70746/sreevalsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-02-24**:
Try running with PIP

```
sudo pip install defusedxml
```

**Comment by [Sreevalsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/70746/sreevalsan/) on 2021-02-24**:
wow, thank you @Ranjith, it got worked, im really happy. Thank you a lot......

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-02-24**:
I would recommend you please look at this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/260377/no-module-named-defusedxmlxmlrpc/?answer=313854#post-id-313854), It is providing a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running with PIP

sudo pip install defusedxml

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-02-24**:
If you got your answer then mark this answer as correct by ticking it, so that can be helpful for other users.